# Pass by copy of reference may be causing unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am trying to build a BabylonJS app inside of ObservableJS.  I've already made an ObservableJS page with a working BabylonJS app inside, just by writing BabylonJS code inside a code cell.  So I know that in principle this works.  To get it working I included an HTML canvas element,

```
<canvas id="lib"></canvas>
```

and then in an OJS cell, used a jQuery to get the canvas and then write a BabylonJS app with it.

However, I'm also trying to abstract a bunch of the functions that I will be using over and over, into a library of helper functions.  I've put them into an NPM module and published it has `babylon-helper-lib`.  In particular, one of the helper functions is the following:

```
export let twodgrid = function(scene: Scene, width=20, height=20, name="box") {
    const box = MeshBuilder.CreateBox(name, {width:width,height:height,depth:.2}, scene);
    
    const boxmat = new GridMaterial(`${name}_mat`, scene);
    boxmat.majorUnitFrequency = 2;
    boxmat.useMaxLine = false;
    
    box.material = boxmat;

    return {box, boxmat};
}
```

I've tested this function outside the context of OJS and can confirm that it works as intended.  Basically it draws a box with some styling.

Then in a webpage with OJS, I have included a canvas element with id `lib`:

```
{
    const LIB = await import("https://esm.sh/babylon-helper-lib");

    const bag = LIB.init("#lib");
    const scene = bag.scene;
    const planebag = LIB.twodgrid(scene);
    // console.log(planebag.box);

    bag.engine.runRenderLoop( () => {
        scene.render();
    });
}
```

Again this is code that I've tested outside of OJS and can confirm that it works as intended.

However, when run inside an OJS cell, I don't get any console errors in the web browser, but it simply does not draw the box.

---

My best guess about why this might be happening, is that JavaScript is pass-by-copy-of-reference.  So although I am passing the `scene` into `CreateBox`, maybe somewhere along the way the scene is getting copied and the box is created on the copy.  I wouldn't have thought so, because it should just be mutating the properties of the scene at the referenced address, so I would think that `scene` is the scene being mutated.  But it's still my best guess.  I tried checking the docs on how `CreateBox` works, but I couldn't find the source code and the given description doesn't help me to understand how it works.

On the other hand, it just now occurs to me that actually my helper library is written in TypeScript, and compiled to JavaScript.  But then again I'm pretty sure TypeScript is also pass-by-reference, so I'm not sure that explains anything.

---

I'm not exactly sure why the question was closed, the code should be reproducible and minimal.  But I'll guess that maybe my expectation about the behavior of the program wasn't stated clearly enough.  I expect the code to produce a BabylonJS app which contains a box.  Instead, it produces a BabylonJS app with nothing in it.

---

I guess there needs to be a direct question: Why does my expected behavior not occur, and how can I make it occur?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. Did you ask a question? I didn't find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @jabaa It does not.

Comment: What's missing in the other question? It describes how objects and variables work in JavaScript and what happens when a function is called. Can you create and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The statement _"TypeScript is also pass-by-reference"_ doesn't make sense. TypeScript doesn't have a runtime engine. You can't run TypeScript code. TypeScript has to be transpiled to another language, usually JavaScript, and the transpiled code is run. Even `ts-node` and Deno transpile the code under the hood and run JavaScript.

Comment: @jabaa The above contains a minimal reproducible code, in which I described what I expected to happen but didn't.  The question is why doesn't that happen, and how can I make it happen.

Comment: It's not complete. Other people have to fill the large gaps to reproduce the problem. Have you tried stepping line by line through your code with your debugger?

Comment: @jabaa I'm not sure what's incomplete about it -- it runs in OJS and therefore does not require a full HTML document.  Code is entered into cells, and therefore, this is the only code needed in an OJS notebook.  There is no error, as explained in the question, so I'm not sure what a debugger would do.

Comment: A debugger would show you the values of the variables in each step and also it shows you the exact code flow. You can step into functions and see why your code doesn't work. You use a debugger when you're looking for logical problems, not only for errors.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem outside of OJS, e.g. in Node.js?

Comment: @jabaa As described in the post, no, this code produced the expected results outside of OJS.

Comment: So it looks like there is a problem in OJS. Maybe you should ask their support or create an issue.

Comment: @jabaa Huh I thought this was a place to ask such questions.  I stand corrected.

Comment: This is about programming questions, not about bugs in third-party platforms. If it works in other JavaScript runtime environments and not in OJS, it's probably a bug in their engine. They are the only people who can fix it.

Comment: @jabaa Ah, so we should mark for closure all the questions having to do with JetBrains, because although it might have to do with programming, if the problem stems from the development environment then it's not appropriate.  Well, in either case, this was sufficiently unfriendly enough to convince me that I'm not welcome here.